# How to fetch images from External Storage in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to fetch images from Mobile External Storage,
I added permissions in my manifest.xml

error I getting in myconsole

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.learning.essentials, PID: 10988
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.learning.essentials.ui.main.Fragment_page.imageReader(Fragment_page.java:132)
```

Here is my fragment.java code

```
public class Fragment_page extends Fragment {
    View status_permission;
    View status_granted;
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<File> list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wa__status, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Find Ids
        status_permission = view.findViewById(R.id.status_permission);
        status_granted = view.findViewById(R.id.status_granted);
        Button allow_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.status_allow_btn);
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.imagegrideView);

        list = imageReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        gridView.setAdapter(new gridAdapter());

        gridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("clicked!");
            }
        });

        //Visibility Gone
        status_granted.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        allow_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1
                    );
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1
                    );
                }
            }
        });

        //Main Permission and Visibility goes here
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1
            );
        } else {
            status_permission.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            status_granted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public class gridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View convtView = null;

            if (convtView ==  null){
                convtView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_row_layout, parent, false);
                ImageView imgview = convtView.findViewById(R.id.imagegrideView);
                imgview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(list.get(position).toString()));
            }

            return convtView;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<File> imageReader(File externalStorageDirectory) {

        ArrayList<File> b = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = externalStorageDirectory.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

            if (files[i].isDirectory()){
                b.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));
            } else {
                if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")){
                    b.add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            status_permission.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            status_granted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

I facing the error in this line.

```
list = imageReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

In my AndroidStudio Editor I getting this in Underline

```
getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

please help me I am Beginner in Android and I Learning,
Thanks in advance =)

Comment: [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392853/6926168). and Have you added runtime permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per new Android 11 Scoped Storage, you can save you files and images in the internal app directory it is using external memory so let's check this code:

```
val fileUri =File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
        "folderName")
```

it will give uri from internal storage and check this for whole understanding: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-access-files

Comment: I think you are using this code in android 10+ device right,

Comment: please check above url given by me because there everything has been mentioned